# .net can't save more than 214 attachments from Outlook library

Tags: .net, outlook, email-attachments

I'm trying to save the attachements for a number of mail items.
The process loops smoothly untill i try to save the 215th attachments when the folling error occurs.

"Cannot save the attachment. Cannot create file: MyWord.doc. Right-click the folder you want to create the file in, and then click Properties on the shortcut menu to check your permissions for the folder."

If i didn't have permission the previous 214 documents would not have saved and they did.  Anyone ever seen anything like this ?

Erick

Answer (score 0):

Sure sounds like you are running out of RPC channels. Make sure you avoid using "foreach" loops (they keep all collection elements referenced until the loop exits), avoid multiple dot notation (you get implicit variables that cannot be explicitly release), and release all Outlook objects using Marshal.ReleaseComObject as soon as you are done with them.

Please show the relevant snippets of your code.